# How to make the name display format into point form?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi and I new to javascript and vue js.
I wanna ask how to make the name display in point formed?

[image]

```
    <template lang="html">

    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="labels"
      :loading="loading"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
   <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
   <tr>
   <td class="text-xs-left"><br>Product ID: {{props.item.product_id}}<br>Product Title: 
    {{props.item.title}}<br><br><v-img :src="thumbnail(props.item.productImage)" :lazy- 
      src="thumbnail(props.item.productImage)" alt="" class="thumbnail"></v-img></td>
   <td class="text-xs-left" >{{props.item.shop_name}}</td>     
  </tr> 
</template>
</v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data () {
   return {
   loading: false,
   labels: [],
   items: [{
     shop_name: ''
   }],
   headers:[
    { text: this.$translate('product_being_promoted'),value: 'product_id',sortable:false },
    { text: this.$translate('name'),value: 'shop_name',sortable: false }    
   ],
 }
}, 
mounted(){
this.getProductPromoteReport();
},
methods: {
 getProductPromoteReport(){
   var self = this;
   this.loading = true
   axios.get("/api/merchant/live/getProductPromoteReport")
        .then(response => {
           self.labels = response.data.labels
           this.loading = false
   })
 },
 thumbnail(str){
  try{
    return str.split(",")[0]
  }catch(e){
    return
    }
   },

  },
 }
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
 .action-icon > *{
 margin-left: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
.visible-true{
 color: red;
 }
.visible-false{
 color: green;
 }
.thumbnail{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 }
.promote-product-report{
 margin-top:15px;
 }
</style>
```

my expected result would be the name display in this format :

- RewardslinkTest
- valent228
- stanleyhomies

I have tried with v-for method to display list of the name but failed.
I wonder have any other solution to solve this issue?
Appreciate anyone of you if have solution on this. Thanks.

Comment: What value is in `item.shop_name`? Is it a string or an array?

Comment: @Phil Hi, string

Comment: And what format is it, exactly? Is it always `", "` (comma + space) separated?

Comment: @Phil Ya, u are right.

Answer (score 2):

you could try to split the string shop_name, and loop them: something like

replacing

```
<td class="text-xs-left" >{{props.item.shop_name}}</td>
```

with

```
<td class="text-xs-left" ><ul><li v-for="namepart in props.item.shop_name.split(', ')">{{namepart }}</li></ul></td>
```

Comment: Even this would produce the desired result, the data should actually be returned in an array and be treated as such

Comment: that is true.. but I got lemons, so lets make lemonade

Answer (score 0):

Create a computed property that can produce a formatted version of your `labels` data and use that in your data-table.

You can also use this for your thumbnails too.

```js
computed: {
  formattedLabels () {
    return this.labels.map(label => ({
      ...label,
      shop_name_list: label.shop_name.split(/,\s*/),
      productImage: label.productImage.split(',')[0]
    }))
  }
}
```

Then use this in you template

```html
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="formattedLabels"
      :loading="loading"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
```

```html
<td class="text-xs-left">
  <ul><li v-for="name in prop.item.shop_name_list">{{ name }}</li></ul>
</td>
```

You can skip using your `thumbnail` method.

Comment: May i know what is "...label," stand for? what is the use of that?

Comment: @Becky it's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals). It's like saying _"all the properties of `label`, plus these two overridden ones..."_

Comment: i have tried ur method, but u resulted out like this. 
- R
- e
- w
- a
- r
- d
- s
- l
- i
- n
- k 

what's the problem???

Comment: @Becky see above. I had a syntax error and you also have to use `formattedLabels` in your data-table

Comment: Ya, i changed it and it came out with nothing.